# Merging RGB Channels in FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, rgb

I have three grayscale videos, representing the red, green, and blue channels from a video. I extracted them using the `extractplanes` filter, and sent them through different pipelines.

Now I would like to combine them again. But while `extractplanes` is working perfectly, `mergeplanes` is not. My initial attempt was this:

```
[r][g][b] mergeplanes=0x001020 [output]
```

This interprets my RGB channels as YUV, which is not what I want. My next attempt was this:

```
[r][g][b] mergeplanes=0x001020:rgb24 [output]
```

But according to the error message, `Only planar formats with more than one component are supported.` (Same for all other RGB and RGBA pixel formats I tried.)

Is there another way to put these channels back together? Or some way to convince `mergeplanes` to output RGB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, `mergeplanes` can only output in a planar format: that is, all the first-component values together, then all the second-component values together, and so on. FFMPEG's RGB formats are non-planar: they group the values by pixel, not by component. So `mergeplanes` can't work with them.

However, FFMPEG does support the GBRP (Green-Blue-Red Planar) format. So you can have `mergeplanes` export to that, then convert to RGB from there. Just change the order of the components.